# python operations with sets

Tags: python

I use python only occasionally, sorry for a seemingly trivial question

```
>>> a = set(((1,1),(1,6),(6,1),(6,6)))
>>> a
set([(6, 1), (1, 6), (1, 1), (6, 6)])
>>> a - set(((1,1)))
set([(6, 1), (1, 6), (1, 1), (6, 6)])
>>> a.remove((1,1))
>>> a
set([(6, 1), (1, 6), (6, 6)])
```

why '`-`' operator didn't delete the element but the `remove` did ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you missed a comma:

```
>>> set(((1,1)))
set([1])
```

should be:

```
>>> set(((1,1),))
set([(1, 1)])
```

or, to be more readable:

```
set([(1,1)])
```

or even (Py2.7+):

```
{(1,1)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed a comma when trying to specify a tuple of one element. Syntax for tuples is indeed somewhat tricky...

- A tuple is built using commas, not parenthesis
- sometimes it is mandatory to add parenthesis around it
- an empty tuple is however represented by an empty pair of parenthesis
- not always a pair of parenthesis wrapping zero or more expression separated by commas is a tuple

Some examples

```
w = 1, 2, 3             # creates a tuple, no parenthesis needed
w2 = (1, 2, 3)          # works too, like x+y is the same as (x+y)
x, y, z = w             # unpacks a tuple
k0 = ()                 # creates an empty tuple
k1 = (1,)               # a tuple with one element (note the comma)
k = (1)                 # just a number, NOT a tuple
foo(1, 2, 3)            # call passing three numbers, not a tuple
bar((1, 2, 3))          # call passing a tuple
if x in 1, 2:           # syntax error, parenthesis are needed
   pass
for x in 1, 2:          # ok here
   pass
gen = (x for x in 1, 2) # error, parenthesis needed here around (1, 2)
```